# Assigning value for a class variable

Tags: c++

There are some codes as follows:

```
class A{
    private :
        int a, b;
    public :
        A(int x):a(x),b(a*a){}
    int getA(){
        return a;
    }
    int getB(){
       return b;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a=13;
    printf("%d %d\n", a.getA(), a.getB() );
    return 0;
}
```

The line `A a=13`, I can't understand how it call the constructor and why?
I think there have't any definition about the cast and won't get compiled, but it runs well and called the constructor function.

Comment: If you don't want an implicit conversion, define the constructor as `explicit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're unaware of the **conversion constructor**. A **conversion constructor** is a constructor that takes in exactly one argument and constructs an object of that class. It works like a conversion from some type to your class, hence the name **conversion constructor**.

**Implicit conversion**, which I believe is what's confusing you here, happens when the compiler sees two different types and tries to make them compatible by looking for possible conversions.

As you can see, **implicit conversion** causes quite a lot of confusion (An int can be an A too?!). Therefore, you should be careful of **conversion constructors** in your class and use the `explicit` keyword when necessary.

```cpp
explicit A(int i);
```

When you specify a conversion constructor as `explicit`, this tells the compiler to **not** perform any **implicit conversion** on this type. When that happens, you can only convert by using a cast such as `static_cast<int>(a);`.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 6):

This is called an implicit declaration. When you write `A a=13;`, your compiler is smart enough to recognize that what you really mean is `A a(13);` since you **have** declared a constructor that takes an int as an argument. If you don't want this to happen, put an `explicit` keyword before your constructor, and then you will get compiler errors unless you write `A a(13);` instead of `A a=13;`.

Answer (score 5):

A non-explicit constructor that takes a single parameter can be used as a *conversion constructor*, to implicitly convert the parameter type to the class type.

So that constructor is used to convert `13` to type `A`.

If you want, you can prevent the implicit conversion by making the constructor explicit:

```
explicit A(int x):a(x),b(a*a){}
```

That can still be used for explicit conversions:

```
A a1(13);     // OK: explicit conversion
A a2 = A(13); // OK: explicit conversion
A a3 = 13;    // Error: implicit conversion not allowed via explicit constructor
```